# How to use ActiveSheet to select sheet I have open

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a VBA script which sorts and organises a column in a sheet named "Company_1_Invoice". However, in my spreadsheet I have multiple sheets (Company_n_Invoice) and I wish to run this macro without changing the script for the different sheets I have.

```
Range("Company_1_Invoice[Invoice Reference]").Select
Range("D:D").Activate
```

I wanted to make use of ActiveSheet but I'm unable to do so, as I get a prompt about flashfill. For info, column D has numbers which I then format the cells with a script below

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSheet` refers the active sheet, thus you need to activate required sheet first:

```
Worksheets("Company_1_Invoice").Activate
```

It means you can't avoid mentioning each sheet you need.
You can use `With` clause to access any object's memeber:

```
With Worksheets("Company_1_Invoice")
  .Range(XXX) = ...
  a = .Name
  ...
End With
```

It helps you saving much ink to type letters :-) But it makes the code faster.

You can loop through the number of sheets composing their names:

```
For i = 1 to 10
  With Worksheets("Company_" & i & "_Invoice")
    ...
  End With
Next
```

You can loop through all sheets not using their names:

```
For Each asheet in Worksheets
  With asheet
    ...
  End With
Next
```

Or you can loop through a range of sheets:

```
For i = 3 to 7 ' 7 should be less Worksheets.Count
  With Worksheets(i)
    ...
  End With
Next
```

You can loop through the sheet list prepared on a dedicated service sheet:

```
For Each acell in Range("SheetList")
  With Worksheets(acell)
    ...
  End With
Next
```

To prepare the list use:

```
i = 1
For Each asheet in Worksheets
  Range("SheetList").Cells(i) = asheet.Name
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Then delete unnecessary names and redefine the "SheetList" range.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) 

I put in Company i, etc to potentially keep confidential information out. Unfortunately each sheet is named differently, so I wouldn't be able to use that loop. 

I had hoped to open the sheet required and run the VBA script to format the information, and then move to the next sheet and run the script again.

For background info,  I combine multiple files into one sheet using powerquery. Due to  hyperlinks I have to do some formatting outside the internal editing tool, for e.g. Selection.Replace and was looking for a way to make it friendlier for other users

Comment: Pls. look at update.

Comment: `With Worksheets("Company_" + i + "_Invoice")` better to use `&` rather than `+` in VBA.   1 & 1 = 11,   1+1=2.  Won't matter in this instance, but good practice.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Sure, it can be considered. Just too much programming languages are in use.

Comment: @rotabor thanks for the update on the loops. I have tried this, but I'm met with an error when I try to use the names of the sheet. For some odd reason it isn't able to pick up the name or the sheet number itself. I have tried listing the sheets using the for and next commands, but the error I receive is Next requires for, or for requires next.